# How to define 2D vector which rows are known c++

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

what is the best way to define 2D vector, which rows are known? So basically, I will have something like this:

```
2 3 4
7 5 4 12 4
2 1 0 2
```

I will know how many rows there are (well actuall I will know it only after getting row variable), but each row collumn will vary. So what is the best way to do this? (I am planning on pushing back each row's columns when I will need, if it is possible)

Comment: What do you mean by 'each row column'?

Comment: Well, I mean that at the start, 2D vector should be something like.  
1st row: 0
2nd row: 0
3rd row: 0
4th row: 0, but if, I for example need to store one more variable in 3rd row, could I just push back the third row? Or it's not how vectors work? (I'm completely new to vectors, started to "learn" them only today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is someone who had a similar question http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/12409/. Just Define a vector of vectors.

**It wont let me comment down below**, but in your code you have `tiesiogiaiJungiasi[A.at(i)]` 
What type is A and if it is a vector then is that vector filled with integers if not A.at(i) is your problem. That will give you the element that is at that location not the location itself.

If you are trying to push the element index i from row B into the element index i of row A try something like this.

`tiesiogiaiJungiasi[A].push_back(tiesiogiaiJungiasi[B][i]);`

assuming there is an element in row B at the index location.

Another problem could be that you say that your rows may be of different sizes. Well you should look at your m parameter in the for loop then. If that number is larger than the number of columns (elements) in that row i has the possibility of walking off the array.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding correctly, this seems like what you want is an array of vectors. You can set an array of vectors like `vector<string> myArray[3];` and then push values into `myArray[0]`, `myArray[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly. You want a data structure that will allow you to append to the end of each row. A `vector< vector < int > >` will do.

```
vector< vector < int > > rows;
```

You have to populate this, if you know the max number of rows you could write:

```
vector< vector < int > > rows(MAX);
```

You append to the end of a row using `rows[i].push_back(...);`. Rows are numbered starting at 0 (add 1 to MAX if you want to start at 1).

Comment: Yup, you understood correctly. However, I should have been more precise. I get the row variable after I declare my vector of vectors. Is there any way I could resize only rows of the vector and leave the collumns 0?

Comment: Yes, you call the resize method of the vector class. Read the reference (google std::vector).

Comment: Hmm. I'm trying to do the [following code](http://pastebin.com/BiY1vHGN), yet I get an error. And values in B and A vectors are not greater than n. What am I doing wrong?